# How to select data from Pandas pivot table and fill missing values with 0?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I need some guidance with pandas pivot table below:

my code:

```
def update_graph(Manager):
    if Manager == "All Managers":
        df_plot = df.copy()
    else:
       df_plot = df[df['Manager'] == Manager]

    pv = pd.pivot_table(
        df_plot,
        index=['Name'],
        columns=["Status"],
        values=['Quantity'],
        aggfunc=sum,
        fill_value=0)
```

myData.csv:

```
Account,Name,Manager,Quantity,Status
123,APAC,John,10,closed
1234,EMEA,Mike,4,open
12345,LATAM,Boris,2,escalated
123456,NAM,Jack,1,pending
123456,NAM,Mike,2,escalated
12345,LATAM,Sam,2,open
```

Data returned for 'All Managers':

```
       Quantity                       
Status   closed escalated open pending
Name                                  
APAC         10         0    0       0
EMEA          0         0    4       0
LATAM         0         2    2       0
NAM           0         2    0       1
```

Data returned if 'Mike' selected as 'Manager':

```
        Quantity     
Status escalated open
Name                 
EMEA           0    4
NAM            2    0
```

Data won't display on my graph if I won't provide also 'pending' and 'closed' values for Mike's case. Could someone help me modify the `pd.pivot_table` so it captures `Quantity` as 0 for all missing `Status`(es)?

Expected:

```
       Quantity                       
Status   closed escalated open pending
Name                                  
APAC          0         0    0       0
EMEA          0         0    4       0
LATAM         0         0    0       0
NAM           0         2    0       0
```

Function with reindex:

```
def update_graph(Manager):
    if Manager == "All Managers":
        df_plot = df.copy()
    else:
        df_plot = df[df['Manager'] == Manager]

    pv = pd.pivot_table(
        df_plot,
        index='Name',
        columns='Status',
        values='Quantity',
        aggfunc=sum,
        fill_value=0)
    pv = pv.reindex(index=df['Name'].unique(), 
                     columns=df['Quantity'].unique(), 
                     fill_value=0)
```

Results after reindex:

```
    Status  10  4   2   1 
Name                  
APAC     0   0   0   0
EMEA     0   0   0   0
LATAM    0   0   0   0
NAM      0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove `[]` from [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) for one element lists for avoid `MultiIndex in columns` and then use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by unique values of `Name` and `Status` columns of original DataFrame:

```
def update_graph(Manager):
    if Manager == "All Managers":
        df_plot = df.copy()
    else:
       df_plot = df[df['Manager'] == Manager]


    pv = pd.pivot_table(
        df_plot,
        index='Name',
        columns="Status",
        values='Quantity',
        aggfunc=sum,
        fill_value=0)

    return pv.reindex(index=df['Name'].unique(), 
                       columns=df['Status'].unique(), 
                       fill_value=0)
```

---

```
print (update_graph('All Managers'))
Status  closed  open  escalated  pending
Name                                    
APAC        10     0          0        0
EMEA         0     4          0        0
LATAM        0     2          2        0
NAM          0     0          2        1

print (update_graph('John'))
Status  closed  open  escalated  pending
Name                                    
APAC        10     0          0        0
EMEA         0     0          0        0
LATAM        0     0          0        0
NAM          0     0          0        0
```

Comment: pv returned only '0' values for 'All Managers' when added the above 'reindex' and instead of 'Status' it provided sums. Should I also include column 'Status' in the 'reindex' part? See in my post above current 'results after reindex'.

Comment: @Baobab1988 - Do you remove `[]` from pivot_table ?

Comment: @Baobab1988 - oops, need `columns=df['Status'].unique()`, not `columns=df['Quantity'].unique()`, sorry.